# DateTime compare not following timeline (java)

Tags: java, jodatime, timeline, compareto

[image: Object timeline after sorting]

This is my object order after I've finished sorting them by date using jodatime's `DateTime` objects. I tried using `java.util.Date` and `Calendar` too, but the result is the same. I use a `PriorityQueue` with a custom comparator `(o1.getTime().compareTo(o2.getTime())`, which should work, but as you can see - it doesn't. For some reason, whatever I try, I always end up with a screwy timeline. The objects are never rightly arranged. I tried comparing them by `DayOfMonth`, and then by `HourOfDay` if the days matched but again the result remains the same.

I've been banging my head over this for about 3 days. Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner data structure does (as you can see it in debugger) does not represent the order you'll get items from `PriorityQueue`. Try to go through `PriorityQueue` using `poll()` method and you'll get the dates properly arranged.

Comment: So, you think it's because of the Collection I'm using? I'll try changing it to a TreeSet or something then, because I need to keep the elements in there for a little more time.

Comment: PriorityQueue is ok for this purpose. When you use poll() you will get the element that is on top of priority queue, which is actually the biggest/smallest element. After poll() this element will be removed from PriorityQueue. What you see in a debugger is NOT what you'll get using poll()